# Re-running scaffolding after dropping tables

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

After dropping tables in SQL Server, then re-running scaffolding, the entities of dropped tables do not get deleted.

I've dropped tables manually in SQL Server. Then I ran scaffolding to update the entities in the project. I ran this several times but nothing changed.

My scaffolding command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=DBHostname;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.SqlServer-OutputDir Entities -context MyDBContext -force
```

I expected the entities classes to be automatically deleted by scaffolding. The `DBContext.cs` file did remove all references to the dropped tables/entities. This makes my code build, but the code is not as clean as I am expecting.

Does anyone know how to get scaffolding to remove entity classes to dropped tables?

Thank you.